# Service Local System to run application as admin

Tags: vb.net

I am a new programmer in vb.net 2010.
I have created a application which need to run as administrator (without passing through UAC). It's a malware protection software, which will be installed with the Admin rights.

I am creating a windows service to let it run automatically on system startup.
The service I created is a Local System Service.

Local system service is not showing the main application window after executing the application.
To come out of this problem, I have tried to execute another application with this service. This another application will execute the main application. But I'm getting error.

Now my question is How can I execute application with Run as admin by a Local system service?

Here are the codes I am using on service(1st exe) and on the app starter exe (2nd exe)

Service code:

```
 Protected Overrides Sub OnStart(ByVal args() As String)
        Dim procStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim procExecuting As New Process
        If File.Exists(OwnDirPath & "appstarter.exe") Then 'realtime
            With procStartInfo
                .UseShellExecute = True
                .FileName = OwnDirPath & "appstarter.exe"
                .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                .Verb = "runas"
            End With
            procExecuting = Process.Start(procStartInfo)
        End If
    End Sub

App Starter code:

    Sub main()
        Dim procStartInfo As New ProcessStartInfo
        Dim procExecuting As New Process
        If File.Exists(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "mfirewall.exe") Then                With procStartInfo
                .UseShellExecute = True
                .FileName = "mfirewall.exe"
                .WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
                .Verb = "runas"
            End With
            procExecuting = Process.Start(procStartInfo)
        End If
    End Sub
```

**EDIT:**
Now I'm not getting error on executing Main application exe from the service exe. But the main application window is hidden and running with SYSTEM account.

How can I run main application with User account permission from the Local System Service without passing User account password?

Please suggest me the best.

Thanks
Regards,

Comment: Windows services usually do not have a GUI by themselves. It is common to have a separate GUI application, run as normal process (not service), that interacts with the service by some means of interprocess communication, e.g. shared memory.
What do you mean with "execute another application with this service"? Services are started by the service control manager, on demand or at system start.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I have 3 exe files. 1st file will run as a Local system service (without any GUI) and will execute 2nd exe file(This 2nd exe file will not show any GUI though as it has been executed by a service).. Hence, This 2nd exe file will execute the 3rd main exe file. Now I want this 3rd exe file to be run as admin without asking for UAC. Is it possible? Or any alternative way to run application as admin on system startup without asking UAC? thanks before

Comment: I have added codes on my post. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: The issue is that there may be zero, one, or multiple active sessions for logged in users at any particular point in time. If there's no one logged in, there's no desktop to put the GUI app on. If there are multiple users logged in, which desktop is it meant to appear on? It also sounds like a gaping security hole to suddently have an application running under an administrative account appear within a non-admin users session.

Comment: I am doing it on my own computer on windows 7 and there is only i have logged in. The application path is the Program files. A service cannot be installed without admin permission. but the service is Local system type. Like another antiviruses. I want to execute my application without asking for UAC.

Comment: Please check the EDIT point..

Comment: Cant you execute it with a schedule on system startup with full admin rights?

Comment: Yes I can run it through scheduled task, but i want to use service with the current user privilege. I've tried to create scheduled task from Local System Service application, but the task is not going to create. Simply I want to run it with the current user privilege but execute it from Local system service.

Answer (score 0):

A Local System service can create schedule task. I have imported xml file and created schedule task and its done.